# Tkinter - Only show filled values of an array in a OptionMenu

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, optionmenu

I've the following code:

```
self.array_lt = ['foo', 'bar', '', 'moo']
var = StringVar()
self.menult = OptionMenu(randomwindow, var, *self.array_lt)
self.menult.config(width=30)
self.menult.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(5,5), pady=(5,5))
```

This shows me a `OptionMenu` with the four values, `foo`, `bar`, `(the empty space)` and `moo`.

How can I show the `OptionMenu` without showing the empty value of the array? In another words, I want to show only `foo`, `bar` and `moo`on the `OptionMenu` and ignore the empty space.

The `array_ly` is just an example, I would like to have something general to ignore always the blank spaces.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with `None` as the filter function to filter out values that would evaluate to `False` when interpreted as a boolean:

```
>>> filter(None, ["1", 0, " ", "", None, True, False, "False"])
['1', ' ', True, 'False']
```

Use this when you pass the list to the `OptionMenu`

```
self.menult = OptionMenu(randomwindow, var, *filter(None, self.array_lt))
```