# Search Window Widget Mapping To List Of Elements In Array In Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Have a scenario as described below:

1. There are three different arrays which store

   1. User name is one array.
   2. Country name is the next array.
   3. Food types name in another array.
2. Was looking for a search window widget, wherein its giving the user options like given below in the image attached.

[image]

3. So was looking if there is any "search based" widget, so that when user types the required name in the "Search Widget" it pops-up all the required name starting with the letter entered.  That way can enter the required nick name and store it in a different array as required which will be used for further processing.

Kindly share in your comments, ideas, thought process etc. and do the needful help.

Regards,
"The Search Window Widget User"

Comment: Tkinter has not that many built-in widgets, you will have to implement that yourself.

Comment: @linusg : Is there any docs or article which you suggest on building own gui widget in tkinter ? If so kindly let me know.

Comment: Do you really need to use `tkinter`? For more complex things like you intend to do I would rather suggest a WebApp. In addition you might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478806/tkinter-only-show-filled-values-of-an-array-in-a-optionmenu showing how to filter option entries for OptionMenu Widget.